# Summary Data - Stats models, Regularized fit

Tags: data-science, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have been using statsmodels to create a linear regression model. I am trying to print the summary data. For OLS the required function is `.summary()`, however, I have regularized the model:

```
model = sm.OLS(Y_train, X_train)
res=model.fit_regularized(alpha=0.04, L1_wt=0)
```

The summary for this is
`summary = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults()` as shown here: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html

I can't seem to work out how to calculate the `normalized_cov_params`. I tried the following:

```
summary = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model,res.params,model.normalized_cov_params)
```

but I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'cov_params'`

Does anybody know how to get the normalised covariance parameters?

All help is appreciated,

C.

Answer (score 4):

```
from statsmodels.tools.tools import pinv_extended  

    model = sm.OLS(Y_train, X_train)
    res=model.fit_regularized(alpha=0.04, L1_wt=0)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    pinv_wexog,_ = pinv_extended(model.wexog)
    normalized_cov_params = np.dot(pinv_wexog, np.transpose(pinv_wexog))
    summary = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model,res.params,normalized_cov_params)
    print(summary.summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

#### One problem...

fit_regularized doesn't have cov_params response. But, sm.OLS.fit() yes!

your code:

```
model = sm.OLS(Y_train, X_train)
res=model.fit_regularized(alpha=0.04, L1_wt=0)
```

after res = fit_regularized(...)
you'll need fit model using res again... like this

```
model_fit_regularized = model.fit(params=res.params)
```

#### this way...

you'll getting l2 params... ridge penalized

To get how responses you could receive of anything try print out:

> **print(dir(model_fit_regularized)), follow image below...**

[image]

yes! You'll could:

```
y_hat = model_fit_regularized.predict(x_test)
```

I hope this has been useful for anyone... bye!